# Finding a String from list in a String is not efficient enough

Tags: groovy

```
   def errorList = readFile WORKSPACE + "/list.txt"
   def knownErrorListbyLine = errorList.readLines()
   def build_log = new URL (Build_Log_URL).getText()
   def found_errors = null

   for(knownError in knownErrorListbyLine) {
      if (build_log.contains(knownError)) {
        found_errors = build_log.readLines().findAll{ it.contains(knownError) }
        for(error in found_errors) {
        println "FOUND ERROR: " + error
        }
      }
    }
```

I wrote this code to find listed errors in a string, but it takes about 20 seconds.

How can I improve the performance? I would love to learn from this.

Thanks a lot!

list.txt contains a string per line:

```
Step ... was FAILED
[ERROR] Pod-domainrouter call failed
@type":"ErrorExtender
[postDeploymentSteps] ... does not exist.

etc...
```

And build logs is where I need to find these errors.

Comment: You are searching the text for a match, then you are searching each line, then you are iterating each line.

Comment: downloading `new URL (Build_Log_URL).getText()` could take whole the time

Comment: Do you really want to find _all_ errors?  As in `grep -f list.txt build.log`? Or could you just short circuit on the first error/hit?

Comment: Yes, I need to find all errors

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `build_log.readLines()` to the variable outside of the loop.

```
def errorList = readFile WORKSPACE + "/list.txt"
def knownErrorListbyLine = errorList.readLines()
def build_log = new URL (Build_Log_URL).getText()
def found_errors = null
def buildLogByLine = build_log.readLines()

for(knownError in knownErrorListbyLine) {
  if (build_log.contains(knownError)) {
    found_errors = buildLogByLine.findAll{ it.contains(knownError) }
    for(error in found_errors) {
        println "FOUND ERROR: " + error
    }
  }
}
```

**Update: using multiple threads**

Note: this may help in case errorList size is large enough. And also if the matching errors distributed evenly.

```
def sublists = knownErrorListbyLine.collate(x) 
// int x - the sublist size, 
// depends on the knownErrorListbyLine size, set the value to get e. g. 4 sublists (threads). 
// Also do not use more than 2 threads per CPU. Start from 1 thread per CPU.

def logsWithErrors = []// list for store results per thread
def lock = new Object()
def threads = sublists.collect { errorSublist ->
    Thread.start {
        def logs = build_log.readLines()
        errorSublist.findAll { build_log.contains(it) }.each { error ->
              def results = logs.findAll { it.contains(error) }
              synchronized(lock) {
                  logsWithErrors << results
              }
        }
    }
}
threads*.join() // wait for all threads to finish

logsWithErrors.flatten().each {
    println "FOUND ERROR: $it"
}
```

Also, as was suggested earlier by other user, try to measure the logs download time, it could be the bottleneck:

```
def errorList = readFile WORKSPACE + "/list.txt"
def knownErrorListbyLine = errorList.readLines()
def start = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
def build_log = new URL(Build_Log_URL).getText()
def end = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
println "Logs download time: ${(end-start)/1000} ms"
def found_errors = null
```

Comment: This won't help at all.

Comment: Could you please add some details about the lines count for `list.txt` and `build_log`?

Comment: One more option might be to split `errorList` into sublists and create a new thread per each. So, several threads will iterate over `build_log` simultaneously. Then each thread should merge it's result to some list, and then you will print it. It makes sense based on the `list.txt` and `build_log` lines count. If `list.txt` is really long it might help. But need to test. I'll be able to provide the code example.

Comment: Can you give an example? Thanks

Comment: @TomS I've updated the answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   def errorList = readFile WORKSPACE + "/list.txt"
   def knownErrorListbyLine = errorList.readLines()
   def build_log = new URL (Build_Log_URL)
   def found_errors = null

   for(knownError in knownErrorListbyLine) {
        build_log.eachLine{ 
            if ( it.contains(knownError) ) {
             println "FOUND ERROR: " + error 
            }
         }
    }
```

This might be even more performant:

```
 def errorList = readFile WORKSPACE + "/list.txt"
   def knownErrorListbyLine = errorList.readLines()
   def build_log = new URL (Build_Log_URL)
   def found_errors = null
   build_log.eachLine{
        for(knownError in knownErrorListbyLine) {
            if ( it.contains(knownError) ) {
             println "FOUND ERROR: " + error 
            }
        } 
 }
```

Attempt using the last one relying on string eachLine instead.

```
 def errorList = readFile WORKSPACE + "/list.txt"
   def knownErrorListbyLine = errorList.readLines()
   def build_log = new URL (Build_Log_URL).getText()
   def found_errors = null
   build_log.eachLine{
        for(knownError in knownErrorListbyLine) {
            if ( it.contains(knownError) ) {
             println "FOUND ERROR: " + error 
            }
        } 
 }
```

Comment: seems it's a jenkins. probably @NonCPS required

Comment: Doesn't work, tried

Comment: Either way, you should be using this pattern.

Comment: I updated the answer with a nearly identical third.